# Why can't I create a new action?

Tags: animation, actions

I am new to blender and am having lots of fun using it. I created a character of an online template and finished binding my armature. I was going to create a new walking action when the new action button was disabled. Can someone please help me.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **Dope Sheet** in **Shape key editor** mode. Switch it to **Action Editor**.

[image]